# Sunspot Profile, Match search associated model attribute results in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, associated-object

Want to easy search all associated model attributes 
Asked before still problems with this:

**Profile model**

```
has_one :match

searchable do
  integer       :id
  string        :country
  string        :state
  string        :city
end
```

**Match model**

```
belongs_to :profile

searchable do
  integer :id
  string :looking_for_education do
   match.looking_for_education
  end      
  integer :age_from
  integer :age_to
end
```

**ProfilesController#Index**

```
def index

  @search = Sunspot.search Profile do

    with(:country, params[:country]) # this is a profile attribute
    with(:state,   params[:state])   # this is a profile attribute   
    with(:looking_for_education, "high school") # this should search *inside* 
                                                #the match attribute's, 
                                                #where **match** belongs_to 
                                                #**profile**
  end

  @profiles = @search.results

end
```

## Edit #1

Rewrote the searchable block like in first answer suggestion with a :looking_for_education do block.  Still fails with a undefined method `looking_for' for #

Added integer :id to the indexes still same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## solution:

I finally found the problem, I had some issues in my development database where Profile was not having a Match. + some missing profile_id in the match table, after fixing those the reindex went fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to search on BOTH `Profile` and `Match` at once, but the models are indexed as separate documents and `Sunspot.search Profile do` only searches `Profile` documents.

You need to [configure the documents](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing#ways-to-populate-field-data) to contain all the information you need in one document. One way to do this could be making the `Profile` be the document that contains all the information:

```
class Profile
  has_one :match

  searchable do
    string :country
    string :state
    string :city
    string :looking_for_education do
      match.looking_for_education
    end
  end
```

Comment: self.match.looking_for_education, Match.looking_for_education and your suggestion all results in undefined method `looking_for_education' for nil:NilClass.